# Searching Merriam-Webster with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Before I reinstalled windows, I was able to type "mw" and press tab  to search the dictionary website through the address bar. However, I cannot do it now, how can I activate this again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click on the nav-bar and pick "Edit search engines..." Click on "Add..." and enter the following:

```
Name: Dictionary
Keyword: mw
URL: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%s
```

To add it just press enter.

Once you added it, simply type its keyword `mw` before your search string and Chrome will use it.

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer @Phssthpok :-)